# HTML Text-box related Queries

Tags: html

1. In HTML: How to make the `text-box` values once entered & saved as `read-only/in` freezed mode but still visible?
2. In HTML: How to make the `text-box` value compared with another field value in the same form & result in the `text-box` color change (similar to MS-EXCEL Conditional formatting)?

Comment: You can't do this with just html; to update/modify the DOM of the page you'd need to use [tag:JavaScript]. Also, without seeing your html (how are you 'saving' the values?) we can't really offer specific answers to part 1, and without knowing which fields you want to compare, and what styles you want to apply, it's difficult to offer a solution to the second.

Answer (score 0):

As for #1, use `readonly` attribute. As for #2, use javascript. For example, in jquery:

```
$('#input1').change(function() {
    if ($('#input1').val() == $('#input2').val()) {
        $('#input1').addClass("same");
    } else {
        $('#input1').addClass("notSame");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Socha23 said, use the [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute for your first question.

For the second. It'd be easier to do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konnwat/amdp5/).

```
$('#tb').keyup(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', getTbColor($(this).val())); 
});

function getTbColor(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'red': return '#ff0000';      
        case 'yellow': return '#ffff00';      
        case 'green': return '#00ff00';    
        case 'blue': return '#0000ff';   
        default: return '#ffffff';           
    }
}
```

Not sure what you mean in your comment, but perhaps you mean this sort of this in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/konnwat/syNZH/)

```
$('#confirm').keyup(function() {
    var color = $(this).val() == $('#email').val() ? '#ffffff' : '#ffcccc';
    $(this).css('background-color', color); 
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response.. :) but how to compare it with the other column field in the same form.. ?.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. `$('#yourElementId').val()` will get the value of an input field in jQuery. Do you mean you want it to, for example, turn red if the value doesn't match another textbox? Like when confirming an email address or something?